# Is is correct to use ' we refer to your mail trailing below

Tags: word-choice, redundancy

Is it correct to use 'we refer to your mail trailing below' or is below redundant here or optional.

Comment: It's not idiomatic and only borderline understandable, especially without context.

Comment: *Trailing* does seem to be used in Indian English, but it's [not used this way](https://www.lexico.com/definition/trail) in Standard English. In Standard English, *below* is needed and *trailing* should not appear at all: "...your email below".

Comment: Yes@AndrewLeach; the word 'trailing (like trailing mail)' is perhaps the most abused usage by Indians, of late.

Comment: The sentence would be fine if *mail trailing* were an actual noun. I certainly have no idea what a *mail trailing* might be. If *trailing* is being used as a verb, it's extremely nonstandard. Pieces of mail aren't normally referred to as *trailing* something. In short, the problem with the sentence has nothing to do with *below*, but everything to do with *trailing*.

Comment: @JasonBassford I think it's used in the same way as newlyweds' cars might have **cans trailing behind.** As you say, mail is not usually trailed.